# android SmsManager is not working in 4.4.2

Tags: android

why SmsManager is not sending message from my application in android 4.4.2(mobile) .whether it is working fine in 5.1.1 .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Check the documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html)

> For information about how to behave as the default SMS app on Android 4.4 (API level 19) and higher, see [Telephony](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/provider/Telephony.html).

Comment: An app does not need to be the default SMS app to be able to send messages.

Comment: ok mike..but can you tell me why message is sending while i am sending it through 5.1.1 ?

Comment: @saurabhdadhich Not without seeing your code and test data. There are several things that could be wrong.